# Entropy of t-distribution in scipy: How to input degrees of freedom to digamma and beta functions?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, entropy, gamma-function

The closed-form analytical solution for the entropy of a variable X that follows the t-distribution, derived [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3906043/derivation-of-t-distribution-entropy-closed-form-analytical-solution), is

[image]

Seeing that python has functions `scipy.special.digamma` and `scipy.special.beta`, how can the above formula be implemented in code?

What confuses me is that the functions just mentioned do not take the degrees of freedom parameter *nu (v)* as an input according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.digamma.html). A running example would help

Comment: Hi, are you looking for the python formulation of the equation above? Or, is it that you want to know how does that function works?
If it's the first, I can share a simple code with you. If it's the second, then from what I understood the formula above is obtained by integrating the Shannon formula of entropy, applied to the Student-t probability density. Beta and Digmma functions do take the degree of freedom as an input only as a result of the integration. They are just two mathematical formulas used to simplify the expression.

Comment: Both would be very helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the differential entropy of multivariate student t-distribution, where, dim is dimensional, dof is degree of freedom and cmtx is covariance.

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as sc
def compute_true_entropy(dim=1, dof=3, std=False):
    cmtx = np.identity(dim)
    B0 = 0.5*np.log(np.linalg.det(cmtx))
    B1 = sc.gamma((dim+dof)/2)/((sc.gamma(dof/2))*((np.pi*dof)**(dim/2)))
    B2 = ((dof+dim)/2)*(sc.digamma((dof+dim)/2) - sc.digamma((dof)/2))
    entropy = B0 - np.log(B1) + B2
   return entropy
```

Comment: thanks for extending to the multivariate case. how would the function be changed to accomodate the `std` input. Would that be a vector of different variables' standard deviations if they are not =1? currently, `std` is absent within the function

Answer (score 2):

By its definition, the entropy is defined by Shanoon as:
[image]

Now if you apply this formula to the *Student-t* distribution, you will notice that this one already contains the degree of freedom parameter (*v*):
[image]

As a result of the integration you will have in the approximation both Betta and Digmma. If you can the calculation, *honestly I couldn't*, you will find out that these take *v* as an input just as a result of the calculation. It is not in their definition.

*v* varies between 1 (Cauchy distribution) and *infinity* (the normal distribution).

To simplify the calculations, I used the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.special as sc
v = float(input('Degre of freedom '))
v1 = (1+v)/2
v2 = v/2
Entropy_of_Variable_X = v1*(sc.digamma(v1)-sc.digamma(v2))+np.log(np.sqrt(v)*sc.beta(v2,0.5))
print('Entropy of the variable X, of degree of freedom equal to : ', v, 'is ', Entropy_of_Variable_X)
```

You can pass it a list or something like that to calculate the entropy for multiple distribution.

Comment: isn't the second formula just a re-statement of the t-distribution pdf, except where the inverse beta function B replaces what normally are Gamma functions? https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/7fb35627dbb7e3dec4f14d60b0b58ea399966f46

Comment: Yes. It's the same formula